# getMessage() with arguments doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

In Spring I'm implementing my own `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and I'm overriding the method `resolveCodeWithoutArguments()` to manage the missing keys at the HTML layer. That works very well, the problem is when in the Java layer I want to use the method

```
getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale)
```

That method doesn't get the description of the `code` with the `args` from the property file.

- **Does someone know what I'm missing?**
- **Do you need more info?**

**Definition of the bean**

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="com.package.CustomResourceBundle">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="fileEncodings" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="5" />
    <property name="basenames" value="i18n/messages,i18n/support"/>
</bean>
```

**Method where I'm using the method getMessage()**

```
public static String getBundleMessage(RequestContext context, String key, Object params[]) {

    ApplicationContext appContext = context.getActiveFlow().getApplicationContext();
    DelegatingMessageSource messageSource = (DelegatingMessageSource)appContext.getBean("messageSource");
    messageSource.setAlwaysUseMessageFormat(true);

    return messageSource.getMessage(key, params, "[ "+key+" ]" ,LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());

    }
```

**Property**

```
report_date=Report Date: {0}
```

**CustomResourceBundle class**

```
public class CustomResourceBundle extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

    private String[] basenames = new String[0];
    private long cacheMillis = -1;

    @Override
    public void setCacheSeconds(int cacheSeconds) {
        this.cacheMillis = (cacheSeconds * 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBasenames(String... basenames) {
        if (basenames != null) {
            this.basenames = new String[basenames.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < basenames.length; i++) {
                String basename = basenames[i];
                Assert.hasText(basename, "text");
                this.basenames[i] = basename.trim();
            }
        } else {
            this.basenames = new String[0];
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String resolveCodeWithoutArguments(String code, Locale locale) {
        if (this.cacheMillis < 0) {
            PropertiesHolder propHolder = getMergedProperties(locale);
            String result = propHolder.getProperty(code);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        } else {
            for (String basename : this.basenames) {
                List<String> filenames = calculateAllFilenames(basename, locale);
                for (String filename : filenames) {
                    PropertiesHolder propHolder = getProperties(filename);
                    String result = propHolder.getProperty(code);
                    if (result != null) {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "[ "+code+" ]";
    }

}
```

**UPDATE - Resolution**
I couldn't find why the method wasn't working well, so I implemented the method.

```
public static String getResourceBundleMessage(RequestContext context, String key, Object[] params) {

        String finalMsg = "";
        MessageFormat messageFormat = null;

        ApplicationContext appContext = context.getActiveFlow().getApplicationContext();        
        DelegatingMessageSource  messageSource = (DelegatingMessageSource) appContext.getBean("messageSource");

        String  msgValue = messageSource.getMessage(key, null, "[ "+key+" ]", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        messageFormat = new MessageFormat(msgValue);

        if(!msgValue.equalsIgnoreCase("[ "+key+" ]")){
            finalMsg = messageFormat.format(params);
        }           

        return finalMsg;

    }
```

Comment: Obligatory: have you tried using a debugger to set a breakpoint in your `resolve...()` implementation to see whether it even gets called? If not, you could try stepping through the actual Spring Framework source to see why it never gets there.

Comment: First of all, I edited the post because I had an error when I was calling the bean and I was casting it as a CustomResourceBundle, now it is being casted as a DelegatingMessageSource (I was getting an exception). Yes, I set the breakpoint and the method was being called but that methods is called when the app need to translate a key from the HTML. Now I'm gonna try to override the method getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale).

Comment: In the definition of your method getBundleMessage(), shouldn´t the last argument `Object params[]` be `Object[] params` instead?

Comment: @Mylleranton Java allows both (http://ideone.com/opxz6y), but should give you a warning on the C-style declaration.

Comment: Try using "{" instead of "[". I0ve always used them in validation (for example "{javax.validation.NotNull.message}")